# Elmah xml over multiple instances

Tags: asp.net, azure, elmah

If I choose to have exceptions logged to an XML file in the `AppData` directory and then deploy the website to a cloud environment like Azure, will each instance create its own XML log file or will all the instances write to the same XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a site to auto-scale it will scale horizontally across many machines so you will not have a problem, however you'll probably hit a snag if you try to do log file amalgamation as you'll have a range of separate XML files that you can't view at once.  Your best bet would be to log to a centralised location like Table Storage.  See this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ELMAH.Tables/